# Translating SIMetrix/SIMPLIS help into other language

Tags: terminology, simulation, documentation

> The SIMPLIS Periodic Operating Point (POP) analysis excels at finding the steady-state ON-OFF limit cycle of a stable periodic switching system.

Couldn't you explain me the sense of the sentence above to help me translate it to other language.

In particular, I have no idea how to translate "steady-state ON-OFF limit cycle". 
It would be great if someone explained me this term.

UPD: Really don't know, confused. Couldn't you, please, just say it for me in other words, in short?

This question is about electronics-specific terminology in circuit simulation software documentation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because documentation translation questions are not under the context of electronics design or repair.

Comment: The only thing I might have done wrong is choosing the title of the question.   

SIMetrix is mixed-mode circuit simulation package designed for professional electronics engineers. Its' documentation  is enriched with complicated electronics-specific terms which are worth asking about and discussing.  

Translating documentation of such a software gives non-English speaking engineers an opportunity to use this software in their purposes of electronics design.

Comment: I know what Simplis is - I use it from time to time. It doesn't change my opinion on the suitability of the question for this particular SE site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SIMextrix is great and SIMPLIS being part of it makes dealing with power-electronics easier

http://microe.udea.edu.co/~alince/recursos/software/simetrix/SIMPLIS_Reference.pdf

> In the analysis of a switching piecewise-linear system, the
>   steady-state solution is essential. For example, in the study of the
>   line/load regulation of a regulated switching power system, the
>   relevant information is the steady-state load voltage over a range of
>   line/load conditions. Although carrying important information in its
>   own right, the transient information on how the system settles to the
>   new steady-state under the new line/load condition is not the focus of
>   such a study. To carry out such a study, the load voltage is measured
>   after the system has settled to new steady-state operations under new
>   line/load conditions. Depending on the damping and the regulation
>   circuitry of the system, it may take the system hundreds to thousands
>   of switching cycles before settling to a new steady-state operation
>   after each change in the line/load condition. While carrying out such
>   a study with a brute-force simulation is possible, it can be
>   time-consuming. Hence, there is a need for a special analysis tool
>   that can "accelerate" the convergence of the system towards its
>   steady-state operating condition without going through the actual
>   transient.
>
> The Periodic Operating Point Analysis tool in SIMPLIS is able to speed
>   up the convergence to the steady-state solution of a switched
>   piecewise-linear system that is either self-oscillating or driven by
>   one or more periodic sources that are commensurate in their periods.
>   To invoke such an analysis, the user only needs to add a few lines in
>   the input file. “Statements Relating to POP Analysis” on page 139
>   explains in detail the format of the input statements related to the
>   Periodic Operating Point analysis. “Synopsis of the Periodic Operating
>   Point Analysis” on page 146 explains what happens during a Periodic
>   Operating Point analysis. After reading this section, a user will
>   understand the internal workings of this analysis tool and, as a
>   result, will be able to use the analysis tool more productively. An
>   example in “Example of Applying the  Chapter 10 Simplis-POP 139 POP
>   Analysis Tool” on page 154 illustrates the application of the POP
>   analysis to a closed-loop regulated switching power system

What does that mean?  in short power electronics always results in switching current and ringing around the edges. This slows down simulation packages immensely as they suddenly reduce their stepsize in an attempt to resolve the present step.

Now some packages to get around then just "overlook" switching transients (Simulink does this) to facilitate a reasonable simulation time.

SIMPLIS have some ... lets call it "voodoo" to manage this that produces fast but accurate simulations for switching characteristics.